# What does it mean for $\frac{1}{n} X^TX \rightarrow A$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ where $X$ has linearly independent columns, suppose $$\frac{1}{n}X^TX \rightarrow A$$
where $A$ is a positive definite matrix.

I have two questions about the above statement:

(1) What does it mean for $\frac{1}{n}X^TX$ to converge to another matrix? Does it mean that I'll multiply each element in $X^TX$ by $1/n$, and each element will converge to a corresponding element in $A$?

(2) Why is it reasonable to assume that $A$ is a positive definite matrix? Does this have to do with the assumption that $X$ has linearly independent columns? If $X$ is not linearly independent, is it still possible for $\frac{1}{n} X^TX \rightarrow A$ where $A$ is positive definite?

Comment: The matrix $X^TX$ is always positive semi-definite. Definiteness implies there are no eigenvalues that are zero. The matrix $X^TX$ is a $p \times p$ matrix and it says the columns are linearly independent. The rank of $X^TX $ is equal to the rank of $X$ which as it says is $p$.

Comment: To answer (1), when you speak of convergence you need to define some norm $\|\cdot\|$ on the space of matrices. Then, given a sequence of matrices $B_n$ we say $B_n$ converges to some matrix $A$ if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|B_n - A\| = 0$. As everything is finite dimensional it doesn't matter which norm you choose as they are all equivalent.